# vba worksheet_change for those cells in a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed a macro that checks a value in a range, and depending the value that was before the change it applies bold to some values in a different columns from the same row.
that is working ok And I 'm happy abbout get that.
the portion of the code is this

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
```

Dim KeyCells As Range

```
   Dim valorActual As Long

   Dim valorAntic As Long

Set KeyCells = Range("BF3:BF378")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then



   valorActual = Target.Value
 valorAntic = Rows(Target.Row).Columns("BG").Value


     If (valorActual > 4 And valorAntic < 5) Or (valorActual > 8 And valorAntic < 9) Or (valorActual > 12 And valorAntic < 13) Or (valorAntic > 4 And valorActual < 5) Or (valorAntic > 8 And valorActual < 9) Or (valorAntic > 12 And valorActual < 13) Then

     Rows(Target.Row).Columns("C").Font.Bold = True
     Rows(Target.Row).Columns("C").Font.Underline = True
     Rows(Target.Row).Columns("R").Font.Bold = True
     Rows(Target.Row).Columns("R").Font.Underline = True
     End If
```

The problem is that now that this works as it should, I want to check this from another sheet.
in other words, 
until now the only thing i was checking is column bf. and if a new value was there i check it. but in the deployment moment i realize that this column is changed because another in other sheet had been changed before.
What I mean is that the real change is in another sheet and the column bf what has inside them cells is 
"= anotherSheet!thecellchanged"
and if this "another sheet" changes, the macro from the original worksheet change it is not called,

so 
is there a way to check the changes from a sheet that affects 3rd sheets, and taking the range of the ="anothersheet" cells?
thanks for your website and help in advance

markus
http://www.funhelps.com

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in the `ThisWorkbook` code module, so any references you make to ranges in your macro will refer to the ActiveSheet by default, unless you explicitly qualify them with a sheet reference.

In this case that reference is the `Sh` parameter passed to your event handler: you should use that in your code to make sure you're dealing with the correct worksheet.

E.g. :

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim KeyCells As Range
   Dim valorActual As Long
   Dim valorAntic As Long

   Set KeyCells = Sh.Range("BF3:BF378")

   If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then

       valorActual = Target.Value
       valorAntic = Target.EntireRow.Cells(1,"BG").Value


     If (valorActual > 4 And valorAntic < 5) Or (valorActual > 8 And _
         valorAntic < 9) Or (valorActual > 12 And valorAntic < 13) Or _
         (valorAntic > 4 And valorActual < 5) Or (valorAntic > 8 And _
         valorActual < 9) Or (valorAntic > 12 And valorActual < 13) Then

         With Sh.Rows(Target.Row)
             .Columns("C").Font.Bold = True
             .Columns("C").Font.Underline = True
             .Columns("R").Font.Bold = True
             .Columns("R").Font.Underline = True
         End With
     End If
```